# What is the relationship between these two clauses?

Tags: clauses, sentence-meaning

I came across this sentence:

> Even as the wars in Iraq and Afghanistan morph into shapeless struggles, they have given birth to an extraordinary outpouring of writing that tries to make sense of it all.

I looked "even as" in the dictionary and found out that it is used to express time, manner or that the clause is concessive. However, I am not sure which one (if any) it is, as none seems quite right in this case (the tenses confuse me the most).

Could anyone please explain it to me?

Comment: *Even as* shows a contrast: Even as this is true, that is also true. You could say the struggles and writing are happening suprisingly at the same time.

Comment: What @YosefBaskin said. More specifically, a contrast is being drawn between the fact that *in the real world*, the wars in Iraq and Afghanistan are becoming more and more "shapeless" (incoherent and meaningless, as more disparate adversaries get sucked in, fighting for a bewildering variety of causes and paymasters), while ***in the "world" of writers***, they keep publishing more and more books claiming to "make sense" of what's going on. Note that sometimes ***even as*** simply means ***at the same time*** - not necessarily implying any kind of "incompatibility / contrast", as applies here.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between the two clauses is one of contrast between negative and positive.

It is saying that the clause following the 'even as' phrase:

*The wars in Iraq and Afghanistan morph into shapeless struggle*

is a negative outcome, but that there is a positive outcome that is happening simultaneous with that negative outcome.

The positive outcome is the rest of that sentence:

*they (the wars) have given birth to an extraordinary outpouring of writing that tries to make sense of it all.*

Answer (score 1):

*Even as* is not a constituent in this sentence, except as one might consider it an idiomatic fixed phrase functioning as a subordinator. But *even as* isn't idiomatic; its meaning is completely compositional, given the meanings of *even* and *as*. Nor is it a fixed phrase, since the *even* is optional and can precede any temporal expression

- *Even as/when/before/after/a decade after the wars ...*

The original example

> - *Even as the wars in Iraq and Afghanistan morph into shapeless struggles*

is a subordinate tensed adverbial clause, introduced by *as,* short for (and meaning) *at the same time as*.

- *(at the same time) as the wars in Iraq and Afghanistan morph into shapeless struggles*

Preceding this clause, which is fronted to the start of the sentence, is the concessive quantifier *even*. *Even as* isn't a unit, any more than *big Victorian* is a unit in *big Victorian houses*.

Answer (score 0):

*Even as* means *at the same time as* or, sometimes, *surprisingly at the same time as*:

> **even as** *idiom*
>
> : at the same time as
>  <sub>// They are finishing the job even as
> we speak.</sub>
>
> <sub>Source:
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/even%20as)</sub>

And:

> **even**, *adv.* and *prep.*
>
> **II. 5. b.**  (a) With reference to time; often followed by *as*, *while*. See also even now at Phrases 2.
>  <sub>Later use with *as* and *while* often has the effect of indicating that two seemingly
> contradictory events or circumstances are unexpectedly concurrent. Cf.
> sense A. 8.</sub>
>
> <sub>Source: [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

So:

> *At the same time as the wars in Iraq and Afghanistan morph into shapeless struggles, the wars have given birth to an extraordinary
> outpouring of writing that tries to make sense of it all.*

Sometimes contradiction is suggested (per the *OED*’s later-use sense), as in your example, but not always.

Comment: Why this sense and not the contrastive one? I get the impression it's a 'splurged' usage here, intended to carry both the temporal and the contrastive/concessive senses, but being rather clumsy (the clash of present simple and present perfect).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I added a definition from the *OED* that shows the contrastive sense. Whether contrastive or not, it still means concurrent. I agree that the tenses in the OP’s example sentence seem off.

Comment: Here, but not always. 'Even as Newton laid down the principles of classical mechanics, Einstein ushered in the theories of relativity and quantum mechanics.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: For what it’s worth, the *OED* calls that sense somewhat arcahic: **II. 5.** Exactly, precisely, just. In later use generally somewhat *archaic*.

Comment: _Somewhat archaic._ Not as bad as 'fairly obsolete', I suppose.